# mono delveloper memory profiller do not start up

Tags: xamarin.ios, profiling, monodevelop

I have a very annoying problem. I used the mono developer memory profiller and it worked like a charm. But then I restarted my computer and now the profiller do not start up.

I disabled the "enable profilling" in options and then it prompt and asked if I wanted to enable it again. I tried yes, however it do not start up and I do not know what is preventing it.

The version of mono developer is 3.1.1.

Comment: Try closing MonoDevelop and deleting the *.userprefs file in your project's directory.

Comment: Hi Rolf, that solved my issue - you just saved my day. Thank you so much.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I solved my issue by deleting the *.userprefs files as suggested by Rolf. I closed Monodeveloper, deleted the files, started monodelveloper and did a clean. Thereafter I started the profiller as normal - and it WORKED :P